# Any way to check if values are part of the same sequence $x\mapsto x^\alpha \bmod N$ (with $N = P \cdot Q$)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

For example if we pick a number $N$
$$N = (4\cdot p+3)\cdot (4\cdot q+3) = (2\cdot p_2+1)\cdot (2\cdot q_2+1) = P \cdot Q$$
$$p_2 = 2\cdot p +1$$
$$q_2 = 2\cdot q +1$$
with $p,q,p_2,q_2,P,Q$ different odd primes the sequence
$$s_{i+1} \equiv s_i^4 \pmod N$$
will have $p\cdot q$ different members for most starting variables $s_0 \equiv r^4 \pmod N$, $r\in [1,N-1]$
There are some special cases which only lead to a length of $p,q$ or $1$ but we ignore them here.

In total there are 4 disjoint sequences with length $p \cdot q$.

---

**Question:**
Given 2 sequence members $m_1, m_2$ which are part of 1 out of 4 sequence with length $p\cdot q$ each can we proof if they are part of the same sequence?
(without computing all/many elements of a sequence)

---

*Details*
If they are part of the same sequence we could interprete $m_1,m_2$ as
$$m_1 \equiv s_0^{4^i} \pmod N$$
$$m_2 \equiv s_0^{4^j} \equiv s_0^{4^i \cdot 4^{j-i} } \pmod N$$
for unknown $s_0,i,j$. But which function can be applied to $m_1, m_2$ to receive the same value iff they are part of the same sequence?
By testing around a power $w$ with
$$m_1^w \equiv m_2^w \not\equiv 1 \pmod N$$
$$\not\exists w \in [1,N], \space  \forall m_1,m_2$$
seems to not working out.

---

Example: $N= 7849=47 \cdot 167$ will produce $4$ sequences with length $451 = 11 \cdot 41$ 
(plus special cases of length $11,41,1$) 
Some members of a sequence with that length: $400,455,1720$ (all in same)
and from another sequence with thal length: $392, 2700, 3661$

Comment: How is this a group theory question?

Comment: @Shaun how is that mathematical structure called instead?